# Failing to connect with TPU-vm cause by error "ssh: connect to host [TPU-vm ip] port 22: Network is unreachable"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, tpu

I have tried to connect with TPU virtual machine on linux machine under the network of my company. This failed with such a error reported:

```
SSH: Attempting to connect to worker 0...
ssh: connect to host 35.204.109.31 port 22: Network is unreachable
Retrying: SSH command error: [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
...
SSH: Attempting to connect to worker 0...
ssh: connect to host 35.204.109.31 port 22: Network is unreachable
Retrying: SSH command error: [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
SSH: Attempting to connect to worker 0...
ssh: connect to host 35.204.109.31 port 22: Network is unreachable
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.compute.tpus.tpu-vm.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Here are the version info of gcloud components:

```
Google Cloud SDK 405.0.1
alpha 2022.10.14
bq 2.0.78
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.12
core 2022.10.14
gsutil 5.14
```

The measures I have taken:

- set ssh keys by passing --metadata-from-file option with a pub file generated by "ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "usrname_gmail_com"" when creating TPU-vm
- set default firewall rule "allow-ssh"
- modify proxy configs

I have wasted quite amount of money and time on this, so could anyone give me some suggestions please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide on [Connecting to a Cloud TPU VM](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/users-guide-tpu-vm#connecting_to_a_cloud_tpu_vm) and [SSH into a Cloud TPU VM](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/tpus/tpu-vm/ssh). Try to allow the IP of the TPU VM on the network of your company.